# How to manage intermediate outputs efficiently?

Tags: string, pipe, pipeline, c-preprocessor, temporary-files

I am implementing a C preprocessor in C...

I have the three functions:

1. trigraph replacing function
2. Line splicing function
3. comment removing function

However these functions work separately on files i.e.

First function will take a file and replace the trigraphs producing a temp-file1 as output

Second function will take temp-file1 as input and splice the lines and produce another temp-file2.

Third function will take temp-file2 as input and remove comment and produce yet another temp-file3.

And now the main preprocessing tasks will be performed on temp-file3 and a .i file will be produced as final output.

Now, I have 3 options :

1. Use temp files
2. use pipes
3. instead of intermediate temp-files or pipes use strings(i.e. whole temp-file1, 2 and 3 will be three big strings!!)

I have three doubts...

1. Option 1 seems less efficient than  option2
2. option 2 seems to be perfect but will I be limited by size of that unnamed pipe? (since I have ***single process*** i.e. function 1 2 & 3 will be called one after another) What if temp output size > pipe's total capacity?
3. option 3... Is it efficient, easy over previous two?

Please tell me, Which option should I choose?

Comment: Processes connected by a pipe run concurrently, not sequentially. So the size of the pipe buffer is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe option 2 is how some C compilers are implemented: the C preprocessor pipes to the C compiler, which pipes to the assembler. The size of the pipe buffer isn't a problem because the processes run concurrently, not sequentially. The pipe implements a traditional FIFO queue in a producer-consumer relationship.

Comment: Actually I am not concerned about compiler and assembler I am implementing just the preprocessor(as a project for experience) and function 1 2 & 3 are intermediate steps of the preprocessor... So I need to manage the intermediate results of each of them inside the main preprocessor program. And those functions run sequentially :) ... Any idea which option to go for?

Comment: Why not implement them as threads so they can run concurrently? If not, option 3 is probably best.

Comment: Actually I don't know multi-threading in C Although I know multi processing using fork... But, I was surprised by option 3! Because source files can be very BIG is it good to have a string that big?

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit OS, you can have VERY big strings. And even on a 32-bit OS you can have over 1GB of heap space.